# pass more parameters to freemarker template

Tags: freemarker

How could I check if more parameters were passed to the template that the template needs?
For example the template is

```
<wcw>${ricflair}</wcw>
```

And 2 parameters are passed to the template:

```
ricflair=The president
goldberg=The king
```

I know it is possible to check the other way around (if less parameters are passed) but is there a way to check it?

Thanks,
V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you had to collect the variables referenced in the template (right?), then enumerate the keys in the data-model. The first is sadly not possible with any published API (it's solvable with the `TemplateObject` API, but that's an internal API without backward compatibility guarantees). The second is usually possible, but it depends on what the data-model object is (and what the `ObjectWrapper` configuration setting is).